Can I create a VS 2022 SSAS Project by importing an existing Dimensional cube from our server?
I have seen a few posts asking a similar thing but that was 10 years ago and there seemed to be an import feature which I don't see anymore.
Please note this is NOT SSAS Tabular but dimensional
